# Missing Controller for a plugin in cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-3.x

I bake a plugin and created a controller manually it is working on my local server but, when I move the plugin through the and hit the url cake saying the controller is missing at plugin controller location i.e. plugins/TourPackages/src/Controller/TourPackagesController.php the file is exist in the location, but it still saying controller is missing. i'm attaching the screen shot of it. I am facing this issue for other plugin that I have created.
[image: location of file]

[image: Error for missing controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was issue of routing I have tried multiple combinations of URL for the plugin name and the controller name.

What was done 
in View  (.ctp)

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('<h3>Package Name</h3>', ['controller'=>'TourPackages', 'plugin'=>'TourPackages', 'action'=>'sample'], ['title'=>'Package Name', 'class'=>'', 'escape'=>false]);?>
```

which generate html like `<a href="http://demos.cybershines.com/naturessprout/tour-packages/tour-packages/sample" title="Package Name" class=""><h3>Package Name</h3></a>`

In My plugin router the routing code was 
`Router::plugin(
    'TourPackages',
    ['path' => '/tour-packages'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    }
);` 
This I changed to

```
Router::plugin(
'TourPackages',
['path' => '/tour-packages'],
function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->get('/tour-packages/tour-packages/*', ['controller' => 'TourPackages']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
}
```

);
it taking the "path" /tour-packages for plugin but the controller as "TourPackages"
so when I hit http://demos.cybershines.com/naturessprout/tour-packages/TourPackages/sample cake takes me to the correct location and view. So, I modified the routing code by adding
 `$routes->get('/tour-packages/tour-packages/*', ['controller' => 'TourPackages']);` 
in routing.php and tell cake to execute the TourPackagesController for tour-packages.